# Eclipse 4.7.1a - open file in editor from code/programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, file, compatibility, edit

I want to add capability to my eclipse plug-in to open specified file in new Eclipse editor. I found solution based on `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE` and `import org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS`:

```java
import java.io.File;
import org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS;
import org.eclipse.core.filesystem.IFileStore;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;

File fileToOpen = new File("externalfile.xml");

if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
    IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    try {
        IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );
    } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
        //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
    }
} else {
    //Do something if the file does not exist
}
```

Unfortunately, that solution is no longer supported in 4th versions of Eclipse and only works with older IDEs.

Is there any possibility to open editor on specified file programatically in Eclipse 4.x.x or make workaround/deal with compatibility?

Comment: Have you actually tried this? What part doesn't work? Don't confuse 'e4' applications with Eclipse 4 which still supports 3.x style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 4 still supports 3.x style code (3.x compatibility mode) so this should still work unless you are writing a pure 'e4' style application.

Comment: Fortunately it is not pure 'e4' app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was quite trivial - when I wanted to import earlier listed classes, Eclipse didn't recognize those imports, so at the first time I thought it is not compatible at all. I make one more research, to find `Fix project setup...` option in quick fix menu. That option just added required dependencies to my feature project, so now they are visible, and there is no more errors.